# Pandas worksheet.add_table AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I created a function to format several dataframes the same way placing them into the same excel workbook.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:\...\weather_WPC.py", line 282, in < module > frame_to_excel(writer, exl = NS_parts, df=dfsp)
File "f:\...\df_to_excel.py", line 41, in frame_to_excel
worksheet.add_table(0, 0, df.shape[0] , df.shape[1] - 1, {'columns': [{'header': column} for column in df.columns], 'name': exl['table_name']})
File "C:\...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 125, in cell_wrapper
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 3329, in add_table
name = header_name.lower()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

When I place the dataframe .to_clipboard() it looks fine. I decided to try a pd.read_clipboard() to see if the error occurs there.

```py
file = 'F:/.../testing_pd_to_excel.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='xlsxwriter', date_format='m/d/yyyy')

dfb = pd.read_clipboard()
exl = {'sht': 'Test_B', 'table_name': 'New_B',}
frame_to_excel(writer, exl = exl, df=dfb)
```

The error did not occur .

The code:

```py
import pandas as pd

def frame_to_excel(writer, exl, df):
    '''
    This function takes a DataFrame and exports it to an Excel file with specific formatting.
    '''

    # Write the DataFrame data to the Excel writer.
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=exl['sht'], startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

    worksheet = writer.sheets[exl['sht']]
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, df.shape[0] , df.shape[1] - 1, {'columns': [{'header': column} for column in df.columns], 'name': exl['table_name']})
    
# because of the error above, the rest of the formatting code does not execute.
```

Here is some sample data

```
    data = {
    "Rainday": [1, 2, 3, "...", 31, 32, 33, 34],
    "Day_O_M": [1, 2, 3, "...", 31, 1, 2, 3],
    "Month": ["Oct", None, None, None, None, "Nov", None, None],
    "Average": [0.01, 0.03, 0.08, "...", 2.85, 3.39, 3.56, 3.71],
    "Driest": [0, 0, 0, "...", 1.01, 1.2, 1.26, 1.31],
    "Wettest Actual": [0, 0, 0.3, "...", 11.93, 12.57, 12.69, 12.69],
    "Wettest": [0, 0, 0.27, "...", 10.92, 11.37, 11.43, 11.38],
    "2023": [0, 0, 0.01, "...", 0.01, 0, 0.93, 1.16],
    "2024": [0, 0, 0.03, "...", 0.77, 0, 0, 0],
    "Pct Yr-end": [100, 100, 175, "...", 27, 0, 0, 0],}
```

Any ideas on how to test or remedy this problem are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running your sample dataframe through a similar program to yours gives the expected result:

```py
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "Rainday":        [1,     2,    3,    31,    32,    33,    34   ],
    "Day_O_M":        [1,     2,    3,    31,    1,     2,     3    ],
    "Month":          ["Oct", None, None, None,  "Nov", None,  None ],
    "Average":        [0.01,  0.03, 0.08, 2.85,  3.39,  3.56,  3.71 ],
    "Driest":         [0,     0,    0,    1.01,  1.2,   1.26,  1.31 ],
    "Wettest Actual": [0,     0,    0.3,  11.93, 12.57, 12.69, 12.69],
    "Wettest":        [0,     0,    0.27, 10.92, 11.37, 11.43, 11.38],
    "2023":           [0,     0,    0.01, 0.01,  0,     0.93,  1.16 ],
    "2024":           [0,     0,    0.03, 0.77,  0,     0,     0    ],
    "Pct Yr-end":     [100,   100,  175,  27,    0,     0,     0    ],
}


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_table.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

# Write the dataframe data to XlsxWriter. Turn off the default header and
# index and skip one row to allow us to insert a user defined header.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Create a list of column headers, to use in add_table().
column_settings = [{"header": column} for column in df.columns]

# Add the Excel table structure. Pandas will add the data.
worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns": column_settings})

# Autofit the columns for clarity.
worksheet.autofit()

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

Output:

[image]

I'd guess that issue is that the "2023" or "2024" headers are actually numbers, which would raise an error like yours:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/python/xlsx/XlsxWriter/examples/pandas_table.py", line 51, in <module>
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns": column_settings})
  File "/temp/python/xlsx/XlsxWriter/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 142, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/temp/python/xlsx/XlsxWriter/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 3386, in add_table
    name = header_name.lower()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```